# What happens if I use `AndExpression` without `CloseExpression`

Tags: c#, subsonic

I have this subsonic query:

```
Select.AllColumnsFrom<Data.Group>()
    .Where(Data.Group.GroupIDColumn).IsNotEqualTo(m_sRootGroupID)
    .AndExpression(Data.Group.Columns.OwnerPersonID).IsEqualTo(gUserID)
    .OrExpression(Data.Group.Columns.OwnerPersonID).IsEqualTo(gUserContextID)
    .AndExpression(Data.Group.Columns.IsCallList).IsEqualTo(true)
    .CheckLogicalDelete().ExecuteTypedList<Groups>();
```

At first sight, it seems that the previous developer has mistaken `AndExpression` for `And`. I know that [`AndExpression`](http://biasecurities.com/2008/07/complex-sql-conditional-statements-with-subsonic-2-1/) encloses the preceding statements inside parentheses.

How is the above subsonic query be translated into SQL?

This is what I'm thinking:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblGroups
WHERE GroupID <> m_sRootGroupID
  AND ( --first [AndExpression]
    OwnerPersonID = `gUserID
    OR ( -- [OrExpression]
        OwnerPersonID = gUserContextID
        AND ( -- second [AndExpression]
             IsCallList = true
        )
    )
) -- first [AndExpression]
AND ISNULL(IsDeleted,0) = 0
```

How is the `..Expression`s being handled if there is no `CloseExpression`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been pointed out by @MikeWalsh in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46840624/7291240), calling `.ToString()` shows what the subsonic query looks like when translated to SQL.

Thus, the above code can be translated into:

```
SELECT * --subsonic specifies all columns

 FROM [dbo].[tblGroups]
 WHERE [dbo].[tblGroups].[GroupID] <> @GroupID0
 AND ([dbo].[tblGroups].[OwnerPersonID] = @OwnerPersonID1
)
 OR ([dbo].[tblGroups].[OwnerPersonID] = @OwnerPersonID3
)
 AND ([dbo].[tblGroups].[IsCallList] = @IsCallList5
)
 AND ([dbo].[tblGroups].[IsDeleted] IS NULL OR [dbo].[tblGroups].[IsDeleted] = 0)
```

Which tells us that calling `AndExpression`/`OrExpression` without a `CloseExpression`, subsonic assumes there is only one condition inside the `AND` statement enclosed in parentheses, thus:

`.AndExpression(Data.Group.Columns.OwnerPersonID).IsEqualTo(gUserID)`

is translated into:
 `AND ([dbo].[tblGroups].[OwnerPersonID] = @OwnerPersonID1)`

---

**EDIT:**

That's what I thought. However, when using this subsonic query:

```
Select.AllColumnsFrom<Data.Group>()
    .Where(Data.Group.GroupIDColumn).IsNotEqualTo(m_sRootGroupID)
    .AndExpression(Data.Group.Columns.OwnerPersonID).IsEqualTo("someownerID")
    .Or(Data.Group.Columns.OwnerPersonID).IsEqualTo("SomeContextID")
    .AndExpression(Data.Group.Columns.IsCallList).IsEqualTo(true)
    .CheckLogicalDelete().ToString();
```

I got this query *(formatting mine)*:

```
SELECT <All columns>

 FROM [dbo].[tblGroups]
 WHERE [dbo].[tblGroups].[GroupID] <> @GroupID0
 AND ( -- first [AndExpression]
   [dbo].[tblGroups].[OwnerPersonID] = @OwnerPersonID1 --Data.Group.Columns.OwnerPersonID).IsEqualTo("someownerID")
   OR [dbo].[tblGroups].[OwnerPersonID] = @OwnerPersonID2 --.Or(Data.Group.Columns.OwnerPersonID).IsEqualTo("SomeContextID")
 ) -- close for first [AndExpression]
 AND ( -- second [AndExpression]
    [dbo].[tblGroups].[IsCallList] = @IsCallList4
 ) -- close for second [AndExpression]
 AND ([dbo].[tblGroups].[IsDeleted] IS NULL OR [dbo].[tblGroups].[IsDeleted] = 0)
```

As you can see, the first `AndExpression` includes `.Or(Data.Group.Columns.OwnerPersonID).IsEqualTo("SomeContextID")` inside its parentheses, which implies that `..Expression`'s continue to include preceding statements inside the parentheses until it finds another `..Expression` (as we can observe on the second `AndExpression`.

Adding additional `And`/`Or` methods after the first `AndExpression` strengthens the proof that

> Using `..Expression`'s without `CloseExpression` will encapsulate preceding statements in parentheses until another `..Expression` is called.

Answer (score 1):

To get the emitted sql just call the ToString method of the query, which will call BuildSqlStatement.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question directly. +1 though coz you pointed the right direction to get my answer